# php session and mysql update

Tags: php

am building a social network, i use php session to allow info to stay on the pages when the user goes to another page, however when the mysql script to update a value. it does reflect the change made unless the user log out and log back in. any ideas?

thanks . . .

```
<?php

session_start();

$login_email = $_SESSION['email'] ;
$login_pass = $_SESSION['pass'] ;

$target_path = "pictures/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path) and

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","naruto") and 

    mysql_select_db("users", $con) and 

    mysql_query (" UPDATE user_info SET profile_pic = ' $target_path ' WHERE email = '$login_email' AND password1 = '$login_pass' " ) ) {

        session_destroy ();

        include 'login.php';

        session_start ();

 if ( $login_email == $_SESSION['page_email'] && $login_pass == $_SESSION['page_pass ']){       


        header ('location:home.php');

} else{

    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

    }



?>
```

$_SESSION['page_email'] 
$_SESSION['page_pass ']

Comment: what does "does reflect the change made" means? make it more clear..

Comment: You are comparing `$_SESSION['email']` to `$_SESSION['page_email']` and `$_SESSION['pass']` to `$_SESSION['page_pass']` and if they don't match that indicates a failed upload? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: i mean that updating the database doesn't update the page, which is the $_session['profile_pic'] that show the picture on the page, unless the user logs out and log back in . . .

Comment: the password match however, and that part of the script works fine

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you show the profile pic on a user's page. If it's through stored session, I would suggest you create a function to return a user information to store in $_SESSION, and call that on every user profile update

```
mysql_query (" UPDATE user_info SET profile_pic = ' $target_path ' WHERE email = '$login_email' AND password1 = '$login_pass' " ) ) {

    session_destroy();

    include 'login.php';

    session_start ();
    $_SESSION['user'] = get_user_info(); // your new function to return user info
```

Comment: yes I agree with you about that, but am kinda new to php really, so I have an idea on how to do that, but it would be great if you could give me some more insight on how to write such a function, the get_user_info (), i tried writing this but its not working out quite well, thanks in advance . . . .